# Mesh is lost in ListPlot3D with some PlotTheme

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

When plotting the following data with `PlotTheme`s `"Business"` or `"Web"`, the lowest `dat1` does not get a mesh at all. But without these `PlotTheme`s, it certainly gets a normal mesh. Is it possible to recover a mesh in the same style?

```
Table[ListPlot3D[{dat1, dat2, dat3}, PlotTheme -> {"Grid", theme}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8]], 
  ImageSize -> Medium], {theme, {"Business", "Web"}}]
```

[image]

The data are as follows

```
{dat1, dat2, dat3}={{{-0.499997, 1.1159*10^-24, 0.00166667}, {-0.447933, -0.00745823, 
   0.00193863}, {-0.329345, -0.0251481, 
   0.00258457}, {-0.185936, -0.0478652, 
   0.00341362}, {-0.00466817, -0.0702993, 
   0.00421323}, {0.17738, -0.063759, 
   0.00390719}, {0.291455, -0.0496345, 
   0.00335362}, {0.361163, -0.0380495, 
   0.00291912}, {0.404419, -0.0294144, 
   0.00260623}, {0.431835, -0.023104, 
   0.00238468}, {0.449641, -0.0184808, 
   0.00222726}, {0.461516, -0.0150467, 
   0.00211387}, {0.469674, -0.0124357, 
   0.00203034}, {0.475486, -0.0103782, 
   0.00196665}, {0.479852, -0.00866813, 
   0.00191543}, {0.483422, -0.00713736, 
   0.00187089}, {0.486726, -0.00564181, 
   0.00182817}, {0.490211, -0.00406795, 
   0.00178344}, {0.494104, -0.00238877, 
   0.00173548}, {0.497943, -0.000816103, 
   0.00169024}, {0.499985, -4.80375*10^-6, 0.00166681}, {-0.499997, 
   0., 0.00166667}, {-0.447933, 0., 0.00166667}, {-0.329345, 0., 
   0.00166667}, {-0.185936, 0., 0.00166667}, {-0.00466817, 0., 
   0.00166667}, {0.17738, 0., 0.00166667}, {0.291455, 0., 
   0.00166667}, {0.361163, 0., 0.00166667}, {0.404419, 0., 
   0.00166667}, {0.431835, 0., 0.00166667}, {0.449641, 0., 
   0.00166667}, {0.461516, 0., 0.00166667}, {0.469674, 0., 
   0.00166667}, {0.475486, 0., 0.00166667}, {0.479852, 0., 
   0.00166667}, {0.483422, 0., 0.00166667}, {0.486726, 0., 
   0.00166667}, {0.490211, 0., 0.00166667}, {0.494104, 0., 
   0.00166667}, {0.497943, 0., 0.00166667}, {0.499985, 0., 
   0.00166667}, {-0.499997, -1.1159*10^-24, 0.00166667}, {-0.447933, 
   0.00745823, 0.00193863}, {-0.329345, 0.0251481, 
   0.00258457}, {-0.185936, 0.0478652, 0.00341362}, {-0.00466817, 
   0.0702993, 0.00421323}, {0.17738, 0.063759, 0.00390719}, {0.291455,
    0.0496345, 0.00335362}, {0.361163, 0.0380495, 
   0.00291912}, {0.404419, 0.0294144, 0.00260623}, {0.431835, 
   0.023104, 0.00238468}, {0.449641, 0.0184808, 
   0.00222726}, {0.461516, 0.0150467, 0.00211387}, {0.469674, 
   0.0124357, 0.00203034}, {0.475486, 0.0103782, 
   0.00196665}, {0.479852, 0.00866813, 0.00191543}, {0.483422, 
   0.00713736, 0.00187089}, {0.486726, 0.00564181, 
   0.00182817}, {0.490211, 0.00406795, 0.00178344}, {0.494104, 
   0.00238877, 0.00173548}, {0.497943, 0.000816103, 
   0.00169024}, {0.499985, 4.80375*10^-6, 
   0.00166681}}, {{-0.499775, -2.23009*10^-29, 
   0.015}, {-0.447627, -0.0062654, 0.0174493}, {-0.328834, -0.0211268,
    0.0232669}, {-0.185163, -0.0402156, 
   0.0307354}, {-0.00369302, -0.0590547, 
   0.0379344}, {0.177888, -0.0534841, 
   0.0351482}, {0.291581, -0.041624, 
   0.0301654}, {0.361089, -0.0319073, 
   0.0262588}, {0.404244, -0.0246666, 
   0.0234461}, {0.43161, -0.0193754, 
   0.0214547}, {0.449392, -0.0154988, 
   0.0200398}, {0.461257, -0.0126193, 
   0.0190205}, {0.469412, -0.0104297, 
   0.0182696}, {0.475225, -0.00870432, 
   0.0176971}, {0.479594, -0.00727014, 
   0.0172366}, {0.483169, -0.00598633, 
   0.0168362}, {0.486479, -0.004732, 
   0.0164521}, {0.489972, -0.00341197, 
   0.0160499}, {0.493872, -0.00200358, 
   0.0156187}, {0.497717, -0.000684506, 
   0.015212}, {0.499763, -4.02915*10^-6, 0.0150012}, {-0.499775, 0., 
   0.015}, {-0.447627, 0., 0.015}, {-0.328834, 0., 0.015}, {-0.185163,
    0., 0.015}, {-0.00369302, 0., 0.015}, {0.177888, 0., 
   0.015}, {0.291581, 0., 0.015}, {0.361089, 0., 0.015}, {0.404244, 
   0., 0.015}, {0.43161, 0., 0.015}, {0.449392, 0., 0.015}, {0.461257,
    0., 0.015}, {0.469412, 0., 0.015}, {0.475225, 0., 
   0.015}, {0.479594, 0., 0.015}, {0.483169, 0., 0.015}, {0.486479, 
   0., 0.015}, {0.489972, 0., 0.015}, {0.493872, 0., 
   0.015}, {0.497717, 0., 0.015}, {0.499763, 0., 0.015}, {-0.499775, 
   2.23009*10^-29, 0.015}, {-0.447627, 0.0062654, 
   0.0174493}, {-0.328834, 0.0211268, 0.0232669}, {-0.185163, 
   0.0402156, 0.0307354}, {-0.00369302, 0.0590547, 
   0.0379344}, {0.177888, 0.0534841, 0.0351482}, {0.291581, 0.041624, 
   0.0301654}, {0.361089, 0.0319073, 0.0262588}, {0.404244, 0.0246666,
    0.0234461}, {0.43161, 0.0193754, 0.0214547}, {0.449392, 0.0154988,
    0.0200398}, {0.461257, 0.0126193, 0.0190205}, {0.469412, 
   0.0104297, 0.0182696}, {0.475225, 0.00870432, 
   0.0176971}, {0.479594, 0.00727014, 0.0172366}, {0.483169, 
   0.00598633, 0.0168362}, {0.486479, 0.004732, 0.0164521}, {0.489972,
    0.00341197, 0.0160499}, {0.493872, 0.00200358, 
   0.0156187}, {0.497717, 0.000684506, 0.015212}, {0.499763, 
   4.02915*10^-6, 0.0150012}}, {{-0.499375, -1.99206*10^-21, 
   0.025}, {-0.447075, -0.00311103, 0.0290871}, {-0.327912, -0.010491,
    0.0387955}, {-0.183768, -0.0199738, 
   0.0512644}, {-0.00193427, -0.0293216, 
   0.0632699}, {0.178798, -0.0264874, 
   0.0585302}, {0.291806, -0.0206033, 
   0.0502241}, {0.360955, -0.0157925, 
   0.0437245}, {0.403929, -0.0122092, 
   0.0390471}, {0.431205, -0.00959079, 
   0.0357357}, {0.448944, -0.00767234, 
   0.0333829}, {0.460791, -0.00624721, 
   0.0316879}, {0.46894, -0.00516351, 
   0.0304392}, {0.474755, -0.00430945, 
   0.0294868}, {0.47913, -0.0035995, 
   0.0287209}, {0.482714, -0.00296393, 
   0.0280548}, {0.486035, -0.00234293, 
   0.0274159}, {0.489541, -0.00168937, 
   0.0267468}, {0.493454, -0.000992039, 
   0.0260294}, {0.497311, -0.000338924, 
   0.0253527}, {0.499362, -1.99498*10^-6, 0.0250021}, {-0.499375, 0., 
   0.025}, {-0.447075, 0., 0.025}, {-0.327912, 0., 0.025}, {-0.183768,
    0., 0.025}, {-0.00193427, 0., 0.025}, {0.178798, 0., 
   0.025}, {0.291806, 0., 0.025}, {0.360955, 0., 0.025}, {0.403929, 
   0., 0.025}, {0.431205, 0., 0.025}, {0.448944, 0., 
   0.025}, {0.460791, 0., 0.025}, {0.46894, 0., 0.025}, {0.474755, 0.,
    0.025}, {0.47913, 0., 0.025}, {0.482714, 0., 0.025}, {0.486035, 
   0., 0.025}, {0.489541, 0., 0.025}, {0.493454, 0., 
   0.025}, {0.497311, 0., 0.025}, {0.499362, 0., 0.025}, {-0.499375, 
   1.99206*10^-21, 0.025}, {-0.447075, 0.00311103, 
   0.0290871}, {-0.327912, 0.010491, 0.0387955}, {-0.183768, 
   0.0199738, 0.0512644}, {-0.00193427, 0.0293216, 
   0.0632699}, {0.178798, 0.0264874, 0.0585302}, {0.291806, 0.0206033,
    0.0502241}, {0.360955, 0.0157925, 0.0437245}, {0.403929, 
   0.0122092, 0.0390471}, {0.431205, 0.00959079, 
   0.0357357}, {0.448944, 0.00767234, 0.0333829}, {0.460791, 
   0.00624721, 0.0316879}, {0.46894, 0.00516351, 
   0.0304392}, {0.474755, 0.00430945, 0.0294868}, {0.47913, 0.0035995,
    0.0287209}, {0.482714, 0.00296393, 0.0280548}, {0.486035, 
   0.00234293, 0.0274159}, {0.489541, 0.00168937, 
   0.0267468}, {0.493454, 0.000992039, 0.0260294}, {0.497311, 
   0.000338924, 0.0253527}, {0.499362, 1.99498*10^-6, 0.0250021}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeshFunctions` for the two themes is `Function[{x,y,z},z]`. So an *almost* flat surface does not show any mesh lines.

```
MeshFunctions /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Business", Plot3D]
```

> `` {Function[{System`PlotThemeDump`x, System`PlotThemeDump`y, 
>      System`PlotThemeDump`z}, System`PlotThemeDump`z]} ``

An alternative is to add the option `MeshFunctions -> {#2&}`. But then we do not get mesh lines equally spaced in the z direction:

```
Table[ListPlot3D[{dat1, dat2, dat3}, PlotTheme -> {"Grid", theme}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8]], 
  ImageSize -> Medium], {theme, {"Business", "Web"}}]
```

[image]

To get the mesh lines to *look* equally-spaced, we can plot `dat1` separately with the option `MeshFunctions -> {#2&}` and combine the plots using `Show`:

```
Module[{colors =
   ("DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[#, Plot3D]))[[;; 3]]},        
  Show[ListPlot3D[{dat2, dat3}, PlotTheme -> {"Grid", #}, 
     PlotStyle -> colors[[2 ;;]], BaseStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.8]], 
     ImageSize -> Medium], 
    ListPlot3D[dat1, PlotTheme -> {"Grid", #}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, BaseStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.8]]], 
    PlotRange -> All]] & /@ {"Business", "Web"}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your solution! One minor question: why do the meshes for `dat2` `dat3` become denser than the original?

Comment: @xiaohuamao, meshes for `dat2` and `dat3` are denser than the original because the same number of meshes is drawn in a smaller vertical interval (vertical range of `dat2` and `dat3` is smaller than the vertical range for the three data sets).